# RoR | Best Practices when abstracting an Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My task is to abstract/inherit an active record class. I'm making a blog where post is a base super with title, slug dates etc... all the redundant stuff you would expect to find.

Here's where things take a turn, I want to sub class out Post into many other sub post types such as audio post, video post, image post, vanilla post. I think you get the point. Obviously each sub type will have their own respective attributes and members.

1. Instead of creating a name, slug, etc., for each sub post type, what is the best practice to inherit or possibly interface the base class? ("I do favor composition over inheritance")
2. Once I figure out how to properly abstract out my models, I would like to then figure out some polymorphic way to say something like Blog.find(1).posts and get an array of all the posts types.

I realize that this may not be performance optimal to query all the post types in a polymorphic way so feel free to seguest a better way.

Comment: Why not just use a general `Post` model and have a `type` field? Do you want separate tables for image posts, audio posts, etc?

Answer (score 1):

While I personally also prefer composition over inheritance, ActiveRecord does not. In this case, if you want to use tools that ActiveRecord offers, you should take a look at [Single Table Inheritance](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815), which would take care of both of your questions. It does use inheritance, however.

Switching to a non-ActiveRecord orm may offer you a way of doing this without having to do everything via inheritance. I've used [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), which prefers composition, with success in the past, but it isn't as feature-packed as ActiveRecord and may not offer what you need.

Comment: I will take your advice and look into single table inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Other then single table inheritance, you may also consider using `has_one` association.

All your sub-types has one post-info, which is the general post name, slug etc (and a post-info belongs to a sub-type polymorphically).

In this way, you would have a table of post-info, and tables for every sub-types.

However, in the model you have to do a little bit more handling:

```
class PostInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :polymorphic => true
  # will need these 2 fields: :post_id, :post_type (might be AudioPost, ImagePost, etc)
end

class AudioPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :post_info, :as => :post

  # you may also want these:
  accept_nested_attributes_for :post_info
  delegate :name, :slug, :posted_at, :to => :post_info
end
```

So now if you want to get all the posts, you may:

```
Blog.find(1).post_infos

post_info.post # => audio_post, image_post, or whatever depending on post_type
```

If you don't want to use `.post_infos`, you may also change all those names, such as:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :actual_post # actual_post_id, actual_post_type
end

class AudioPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :post, :as => :actual_post
  accept_nested_attributes_for :post
  delegate :name, :slug, :posted_at, :to => :post
end
```

Now, you have:

```
posts = Blog.find(1).posts

actual_post = posts.first.actual_post # => an audio_post instance

actual_post.name # => same as actual_post.post.name, so you do not need the name field in the AudioPost model
```